# Kotlin: limitedParallelism is not limiting parallelism

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am lauching several coroutines but with `Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(1)` dispatcher, I would expect them to execute one by one.

```kotlin
@Test fun `testParallelism`(){
        runBlocking {
            val maxParallel = 1
            val ctx =Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(maxParallel)

            val max = AtomicLong(Long.MIN_VALUE)
            val counter = AtomicLong(0)
            (0..1000).map {
                CoroutineScope(ctx).launch(ctx) {
                    val c = counter.incrementAndGet()
                    max.set(Math.max(max.get(), c))
                    delay(100)
                    counter.decrementAndGet()
                }
            }.joinAll()

            // max is 1000
            assertTrue { max.get() <= maxParallel }
        }

    }
```

However the in the above code the assertion fails. Looks like all the coroutines are launched concurrently at the same time. Raising the counter to `1000`.

Is there something I am doing wrong in my test code or I understood the api wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You confuse **parallelism** and **concurrency**. You even use them interchangeably, but they mean different things.

**parallelism** is how many coroutines can run **at exactly the same time**. **concurrency** means how many logical tasks could **run in an overlapping time**, so how many tasks could have started, but not yet completed at any time.

If we set parallelism to 1 that means only one coroutine could be actively executing at a time, but if it waits for anything or just yields, another coroutine could jump in (by suspending the first). Setting concurrency to 1 means coroutines are executed sequentially - next coroutine starts only when the previous completed.

We control parallelism using `Dispatcher.limitedParallelism()`, as you just did. We control concurrency using a [Mutex](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-mutex/) or [Semaphore](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-semaphore/):

```kotlin
val lock = Mutex()

val max = AtomicLong(Long.MIN_VALUE)
val counter = AtomicLong(0)
(0..1000).map {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        lock.withLock {
            val c = counter.incrementAndGet()
            max.set(Math.max(max.get(), c))
            delay(100)
            counter.decrementAndGet()
        }
    }
}.joinAll()
```

BTW, as long as we limit the concurrency as above, we don't need an `AtomicLong` (nor volatile) - regular `var counter = 0L` should do.

Comment: Thats it!! I read the document wrong. I imagined that `limitedParallelism` is `limitedCocurrency`. So there is no way to limit the concurrency in a kotilinic way?

Comment: @MangatRaiModi What do you mean there is no way to limit the concurrency? My answer includes an example on how to limit the concurrency in coroutines :-)

Comment: I understand I can do it with a counting semaphore but is there nothing from the `kotlinx.coroutines` lib?

Comment: @MangatRaiModi `Mutex` and `Semaphore` **are** utils provided by the `kotlinx.coroutines` lib.

Comment: My bad. I got confused. I thought Mutex is Java just like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Comment: BTW, we shouldn't use standard Java synchronization utils with coroutines (locks, mutexes, synchronized blocks, blocking queue, etc.) as they synchronize by blocking the thread, and we shouldn't block threads inside coroutines. This is why Kotlin provides its own utils.